# UIwebview touch event

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, webview

I am using a webview and on that web view i have a image. I want to know how i detect touch event of image of webview. I have o open a new view when image is touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the content of the webView, you might have success turning the image into a link, then in your UIWebViewDelegate, implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method and check for the image link's URL using the `(NSURLRequest *)request` parameter.

If you don't have control of the webView's HTML content, but the image does have an ID, you could make it a link using UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to run some javascript and "linkify" the image.

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` inherits from `UIView` so you could try overriding:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Not sure how much control of the contents of the UIWebView you will have though and if you will be able to figure out the location of the image.